# robobrowser scrape page with login

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape, robobrowser

I am trying to scrape a page but I have to go pass the login page, which I am not being able to do for some reason. Any help is appreciated since I am running out of ideas...

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
url = 'https://www.briefing.com/Login/subscriber.aspx'
url_content = 'https://www.briefing.com/investor/calendars/earnings/'
browser.open(url)
form = browser.get_form(action='./subscriber.aspx')
form['_textBoxUserName'].value = 'my_email'
form['_textBoxPassword'].value = 'my_password'
browser.submit_form(form)
browser.open(url_content)
```

I am not getting any errors.
Solutions using other python libraries are also accepted!

Comment: You might want to consider using selenium and PhantomJS instead. Inspect the code for the webpage and state to the program that it should click on the fields and insert the text specified. After that make it click on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look into it.

Comment: Is it possible to do scraping past a /login while the /login is disallowed in the robots.txt?